# Error: could not find function "score.sentiment" .while performing Sentiment Analysis using R

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I am working on Sentiment Analysis using R. But I am facing an error while scoring the text.

```
result = score.sentiment(sample, pos.words, neg.words)
```

> Error: could not find function "score.sentiment"

I have executed the same code previously, it was working fine. I have checked all the packages as well. Everything looks fine but ending up with error.Please let me know your suggestions and thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Can you show the package from which this `score.sentiment` function comes from?

Comment: Do you mean function from https://github.com/jeffreybreen/twitter-sentiment-analysis-tutorial-201107?

Comment: akrun : I have used plyr and sentiment packages

Comment: Take it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116938/twitter-sentiment-analysis-w-r-using-german-language-set-sentiws)

Comment: I have the same problem, haven't solved it yet.